# I want my header with a Picture on every Page in my project, but it shows only on Sites with Chapters

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

My code:

```
\documentclass[headwidth=page,a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\setlength{\headheight}{75pt}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\chead[{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{img/abc.png}}]{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Titel}
\begin{normalsize}
\blindtext[3]
\blindtext[3]
\end{normalsize}
\chapter{Titel}
\begin{normalsize}
\end{normalsize}
\end{document}
```

This example shows my header on Sie 1 and 3 but not on site 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default chapter pages use page style `plain` while the other pages use `scrheadings` in your MWE. The optional argument of `\chead` puts the picture only on `plain` pages like chapter pages. To set the picture for both pagestyles, repeat the code in the mandantory argument of `\chead` or better use the starred version:

```
\chead*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{img/abc.png}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[headwidth=page,a4paper,12pt,headlines=4.25]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\setlength{\headheight}{75pt}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\chead*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=4\baselineskip]{example-image}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Titel}
\begin{normalsize}
\blindtext[3]
\blindtext[3]
\end{normalsize}
\chapter{Titel}
\begin{normalsize}
\end{normalsize}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there a general meaning of the * in Latex? or is this only a newer version of the function?

Comment: The starred versions of `\chead` etc. were introduced in KOMA-Script version 3.14. The command `\chead*{Text}` is "only"  a shortcut for `\chead[Text]{Text}`.

Comment: Ok. This overwrites the Style for every page. Now i have to do the same with the footer to bring back the Pagenumbers ?

Comment: NVM this: \setlength{\headheight}{75pt} pushed the numbers out of the Document